# how to check if a dictionary is "connected"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Right off the bat, this is school homework. However we were told that if we cannot come up with a solution on our own using loops, we can either find one online or find an algorithm online but we should cite it. So the question is, given a connected dictionary d = { 'f1': ['f2'], 'f2': ['f3'], 'f3': ['f1'], how can i check if it is connected? The dictionary can also be disconnected, its up to me to figure out if it is connected or not and return true or false respectively. We arent allowed any imports. Im not asking for code, maybe just lay out the steps or pseudo code. Also, the values can contain more than 1 item, so could be 'f1': ['f2', 'f6'].

Comment: Define 'connected' please

Comment: I'm not sure if just asking counts as finding one... And why not just try this yourself?

Comment: You're asking for Graph Connectivity - i.e: how to determine if there is a path connecting every vertex. Your dictionary data structure has keys (vertices) and values (the neighbours of the respective key). There are many algorithms online for this :)

Answer (score 0):

> A matrix representation of a directed graph is fully connected if only 
>   if  the main diagonal contains zeros, because the main diagonal
>   represents the connection of each vertex to itself.
>   Anything different from this represents a not fully connected graph.

This should be a starting point for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could list keys of the dictionary items that are connected to any other item in the dictionary, stage by stage.

- The first stage would be as follows: make a list starting with the
  key of the first item of the original dictionary only. Check if the
  key or the values of this item are similar to the values or keys of the other
  items. Add these keys to this list. This is the list of keys of the
  items that are connected to the first item.
- Second stage: Create another list, starting this time with the key of
  the second item in the dictionary. Similar to stage one, add to this 
  list the keys of the connected items in the rest of the dictionary,
  including the first.
- Stage three: go to the next item and do the same you did in stage
  two. As you can see, you will have a list of the keys of the items
  linked to the item that is compared to all the other items in the
  dictionary. Then, you count the number of groups (stages) you had,
  which should equal the number of items in the dictionary.
- Finally, you have to check that the groups are linked successively
  one group to the next, each time by at least one item (represented by
  a key).
- If this series of links connects all the groups of keys, then the
  whole dictionary is linked, I guess. You may have to try out a number
  of permutations (where you change the order of linking the groups).